# Angular-resource query error

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I'm receiving the following error from `$resource`:

```
Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration for action `query`. Expected response to contain an array but got an object
```

the API is not returning an Array but it return this:

```
{
    list: [...items...],
    next: true,
    limit: 100,
    last: 0
}
```

I need to get the entire object with `query()` and push `list` in my `$scope.items`.

The other `params` needs for pagination or infinite scroll.

How can I do that?

**EDIT**:

This is my factory:

```
angular.module('app').factory('Items', ['$resource',
    function ($resource) {

        return $resource('/items/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
            'query': {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: false
            },
            update: {
                method: 'PUT'
            }
        });

    }
]);
```

Comment: docs explain how to set array or object as response

Comment: I added the factory I'm using, probably you are talking about `isArray`, but even if I declared it I'm receiving that error and I can not get the `object`.

Comment: You can't just use get() instead of query()? From my understanding the only difference between these two is actually whether isArray is true/false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your factory is right, just remove single quotes from `query`:

```
...
query: {
    method: 'GET',
    isArray: false
}
...
```

**EDIT** after below comment

I had exactly the same problem few days ago, which was solved by setting `isArray` to `true`. So I quite confident in syntax, but for me I have slightly different declaration of factory:

```
angular.module('docAccessApp',[]).factory('Access',function($resource){
    return  $resource('http://localhost:8080/documentAccesses/:id',{id:'@_id'},{
        query: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray:false
        }
    });
});
```

Maybe you need to Hard Reload the page so that browser refreshes all the js cache.